# Dynamically fill as much width as possible

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed menubar in the left side. To the right of that I got a section. That section is suppossed to fill 100% of the viewport width minus the fixed menubar width and minus the margin and padding of the section itself.
Now I am also trying to center an image inside of this section - that is the black line that you can see in the fiddle. It is suppossed to be centered in the blue area (the section).

**Issue**

The section is too wide which you can see, by how the image is not centered but moved a little to the right.

**Note:**
It should not be possible to scroll the x-axis

**Code ->** https://jsfiddle.net/n9yyrxfm/

```css
html,
body {
  border-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Dosis", "Arial", "Serif";
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-menu {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 100%;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: 4vh;
}

.navbar-menu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-menu ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 140px;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

p {
  width: 250px;
}

div#content {
  /*margin-left: -140px*/
  margin-left: 160px;
  margin-right: 160px;
  height: 200px;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  background: lightblue;
  transition: opacity 0.9s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.9s ease-in-out;
}

section#sec-home img {
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 76px 171px 87px 171px;
  -moz-border-radius: 76px 171px 87px 171px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 76px 171px 87px 171px;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 202px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 202px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 202px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar-menu">
  <ul id="list" class="test">
    <li id="emph nav-home">Home</li>
    <li id="nav-portfolio">Portfolie</li>
    <li id="nav-skills">Færdigheder</li>
    <li id="nav-erfaring">Erfaring</li>
    <li id="nav-kontakt">Kontakt mig</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="content">
  <section class="animatedFade" id="sec-home">
    <img src="images/portrait1.png" alt="">
    <p>asdfr <span class="navn">asdfian</span></p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use the SO code snippets instead of external links. Those will most likely break, especially when you fix your issue.

Comment: I am sorry what?

Comment: SO has special code snippets in which you can put html, css and js. In your editor simply click the `<>`-Icon next to the image icon or press `Ctrl+M`

Comment: @Bjango See my answer. See if that suits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `position: fixed` for the left sidebar, please use a `padding` of the same for the parent. So instead of the content having both `margin-left` and `margin-right`, leave the content with full width, without the `margin`.

```css
html,
body {
  border-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Dosis", "Arial", "Serif";
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 0 0 0 15vw; /* Change this to navbar width. */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;  /* Add this. */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* Add this. */
}

.navbar-menu {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 15vw;
  height: 100%;
  color: #000;
  left: 0; /* Add this. */
  margin-top: 4vh;
}

.navbar-menu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.navbar-menu ul li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 4px 0 4px 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

p {
  width: 250px;
}

div#content {
/* Remove these.
  margin-left: 160px;
  margin-right: 160px;
*/
  height: 200px;
}

section {
/*  width: 100%;  remove */
  color: #000;
  display: block;
/*  position: absolute; remove */
  margin-top: 35px; /* replace */
  background: lightblue;
  transition: opacity 0.9s linear;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.9s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.9s ease-in-out;
}

section#sec-home img {
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 76px 171px 87px 171px;
  -moz-border-radius: 76px 171px 87px 171px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 76px 171px 87px 171px;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 202px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 202px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 202px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.49);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar-menu">
  <ul id="list" class="test">
    <li id="emph nav-home">Home</li>
    <li id="nav-portfolio">Portfolie</li>
    <li id="nav-skills">Færdigheder</li>
    <li id="nav-erfaring">Erfaring</li>
    <li id="nav-kontakt">Kontakt mig</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<div id="content">
  <section class="animatedFade" id="sec-home">
    <img src="images/portrait1.png" alt="">
    <p>asdfr <span class="navn">asdfian</span></p>
  </section>
</div>
```

This is an issue of Fixed Fluid Layout. Please refer to my guide on [**Science behind Fixed-Fluid Layouts**](https://blog.praveen.science/science-behind-fixed-fluid-layouts/).

Comment: It is still not working as expected, it is overlapping a little. you should not be able to scroll the x-axis

Comment: @Bjango I just corrected it. It was because of `width: 100%`. Check now.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `.navbar-menu` has `position: fixed` it gets ignored by all other elements.

However, since it has a fixed width, you can easily solve your problem using `calc` like this:

```
section {
    width: calc(100% - 15vw);
}
```

Note that you will then also need to remove Margins from your section as to not make it bigger than that.

Comment: Don't use `calc`. It's better to avoid it as it is not fully supported by all browsers and it has some serious performance issues.

Comment: @praveenkumar Idk about performance, but it is pretty well supported: https://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: Ha ha... For such a simple thing, I wouldn't use `calc`. It's definitely performance intensive for redraws.